# Serenity BDD Report showing example in place of steps

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

[image]

```
        <serenity.version>2.0.54</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.0.16</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.20</serenity.cucumber.version>
```

In the report I can see all the task ran but it is not showing as grouped under cucmber steps which can be expanded to see the tasks.

[image]

**Update 1:**
update the dependencies still no luck.

```
 <serenity.version>2.0.54</serenity.version>
 <serenity.maven.version>2.0.54</serenity.maven.version>
 <serenity.cucumber.version>1.0.14</serenity.cucumber.version>
 <cucumber.version>4.2.0</cucumber.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your versions are aligned: see https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core#what-is-the-latest-stable-version-i-should-use

Comment: I have used all the dependencies as per the starter project. Still no luck. 
        <serenity.version>2.0.54</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.0.54</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.0.14</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.2.0</cucumber.version>